Automating Qt Visual Studio 2022 Add-in Installation and Configuration in GitHub Actions
I am seeking guidance on automating the installation and configuration of the Qt Visual Studio 2022 add-in using GitHub Actions. Here’s what I’ve done so far and where I need help:
What I Have Achieved:
Successfully checked out the main project.
Automated the installation of Rust 1.76.0, Node.js, Yarn, and Python.
What I Want to Achieve:
Install Qt VS plug-in: Automatically download and install qt-vsaddin-msvc2022-3.0.2.vsix.
Configure Qt Version and Path in Visual Studio 2022: Use devenv.com to add Qt version 6.6.1 and set the path to the Qt installation in the repository (QT_PATH)
Where I Am Stuck:
Qt VS 2022 Add-in Installation: The installation step for the Qt VS Add-in does not seem to execute properly in my GitHub Actions workflow.
Setting Qt Version: The command to set the Qt version in Visual Studio using devenv.com is not working as expected.
Code Snippets:

name: MSBuild

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

env:
  PROJECT_FILE_PATH: HelloWorld.vcxproj
  BUILD_CONFIGURATION: Debug|x64 
  SOLUTION_FILE_PATH: HelloWorld.sln
  DEVENV_PATH: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.com
  QT_VERSION: 6.6.1
  DEVENV_PATH2: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.com
  QT_PATH: ${{ github.workspace }}\Qt\6.6.1\msvc2019_64

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Install Visual Studio 2022
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.2


    - name: Download Qt VS add-in
      run: curl -L -o qt-vsaddin-msvc2022-3.0.2.vsix https://download.qt.io/development_releases/vsaddin/3.0.2/qt-vsaddin-msvc2022-3.0.2.vsix
      shell: cmd


    - name: Set Qt version in Visual Studio
      run: |
        "%DEVENV_PATH2%" /command "Qt5.QtOptions.QtVersions.AddVersion?Name=6.6.1&Path=%QT_PATH%"
      shell: cmd

      
    - name: Build with devenv.com
      shell: cmd
      run: |
        "%DEVENV_PATH%" "%PROJECT_FILE_PATH%" /Build "%BUILD_CONFIGURATION%" /Out buildLog_Debug.txt

Specific Issues:
Setting Qt Version and Path: The command to set the Qt version and path using devenv.com fails to execute correctly.
Any advice or examples on how to achieve these steps correctly in GitHub Actions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!
here's link to my GitHub repo for more reference: https://github.com/Reeva30/HelloWorld.git

Never used qt-vsaddin, but I know alternative (CMake/premake) to build (not limited to visual Studio BTW) with Qt (within github action).

In the latest workflow run, it's failing due to a Powershell syntax error. See https://github.com/Reeva30/HelloWorld/actions/runs/9927550785/job/27422645837. The closing curly brace is missing here.
