How to integrate Qt Add-in/Plugin into Visual Studio 2022 in a GitHub Actions workflow?
I'm trying to set up a GitHub Actions workflow to build a project that requires Visual Studio 2022 and the Qt Add-in/Plugin for vs2022. I'm encountering issues with configuring the Qt version and path integration into Visual Studio 2022 within the GitHub Actions workflow.
Can someone advise on the best approach for installing and configuring the Qt Add-in/Plugin for Visual Studio 2022 in a GitHub Actions workflow?

Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78730754/automating-qt-visual-studio-2022-add-in-installation-and-configuration-in-github?
